# Side Navigation Bar: Like Mobile Applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a newbie.
I am trying to build a side navigation bar like Hamburger Style Navigation as seen on Mobile Applications.

I am able to build a menu as shown [here](http://codepen.io/aps120797/pen/JWXGpM).

```
<div class="side-nav-menu btn-group-vertical" style="display:none">
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg home-btn">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/atranglogo.png"></img> 
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg menu-btn-in about-btn "><i class="material-icons">info_outline</i>   ABOUT</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg menu-btn-in speakers-btn"><i class="material-icons">record_voice_over</i>   SPEAKERS</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg menu-btn-in schedule-btn"><i class="material-icons">alarm</i>   SCHEDULE</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg menu-btn-in venue-btn"><i class="material-icons">place</i>   VENUE</a>                            
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg menu-btn-in team-btn"><i class="material-icons">group</i>   TEAM</a>                      
                        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg menu-btn-in contacts-btn"><i class="material-icons">contacts</i>   CONTACTS</a>                      
                </div>
```

The CSS is as shown:

```
.btn-group-vertical 
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

However, I want to build a navigation menu as shown [here](https://www.pragyan.org/17/home/) and [here](https://festember.com/16/home/), just like the one seen in Modern Mobile Applications

Can anybody please help me out.

Also, when I click outside the menu, with menu being opened. The menu doesn't close. Please help me fixing that.

Comment: look at this https://www.christopheryee.ca/pushy/

Comment: Hey @mlegg, I don't want to push the content, Can you please help me out?